# Gamma distribution shape parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Suppose that I have $X_i \sim E(1)$,iid, i goes from 1 to n, E stands for exponential distribution, and I want to know the distribution of $\bar{X} = \Sigma_iX_i/n$.

I know that $\Sigma_i X_i \sim Gamma(n,1)$, but how to deal with the remaining 1/n?

Does it affect the shape parameter in the same way it afects scale parameters in location-scale distributions, so that I can say $\bar{X} \sim Gamma(n,n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming independence) your $\bar{X} = \Sigma_iX_i/n$ has mean $1$ and variance $\frac1n$ as the average of $n$ random variables with mean and variance $1$

It does have a Gamma distribution, with density $\dfrac{n^n}{\Gamma(n)}x^{n-1}e^{-n x}$

Some people would call this $\text{Gamma}(n,n)$, while others would call it $\text{Gamma}\left(n,\frac1n\right)$ depending on whether they use a rate or a scale parameter as the second term; for the sum rather than the average they would label them the other way round

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not work like that. The only thing you can conclude is that
$$ n\cdot\overline{X}\sim \text{Gamma}(n,1)$$
which is almost always enough since from here it is not hard to calculate the mean or variance for example.

Edit: I am sorry, you were doing it correctly, also see: [How to scale a gamma distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498029/how-to-scale-a-gamma-distribution)

Comment: How to get the distribution of $\bar{X}$ in this case?

Comment: What I usually do is use the formula (which you can derive or remember): $$ f_{c\cdot X}(x) = \frac{f_{X}(x/c)}{c}.$$ This works always (in your case $c=1/n$)